# How to shift signal to baseband using local oscillator frequency?

Tags: frequency, modulation, spectrum

If the input to a demodulator is a signal having the spectrum shown below, how would I figure out what local oscillator frequency is required to shift the signal to baseband?

[image]

Is there a formula for this? I'm getting no where on google.

Thanks.

Comment: Mix with the fundamental to get to baseband.  (This can sometimes not work as well as expected... any slight differences in frequency (of the fundamentals) becomes a slow modulation.)

Comment: Could you explain a little better? I'm trying to do this out on paper as study revision

Comment: Remember that multiplication in the time domain corresponds to convolution in the frequency domain. Also remember that a sinusoid in the time domain corresponds to an impulse in the frequency domain (at the sinusoid's frequency, and another at the negative of the sinusoid's frequency). The question then becomes: When convoluted with the signal spectrum shown, which is centered around 100MHz, what impulse will produce a signal spectrum that's centered around 0Hz after convolution?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest signal that has the spectrum shown is a 100 MHz carrier that is amplitude modulated with 100 kHz bandwidth information. If *Fc* = carrier frequency, a modulating frequency *Fm* causes sidebands at *(Fc + Fm)* and *(Fc - Fm)*. To demodulate the signal, mix it with a local oscillator at *Fc*. You can write a formula for the output of the demodulator by representing each frequency as a trig function of time i.e. *sine(2 pi F)* or *cosine(2 pi F)*. The important output is *sine(2 pi Fm)* which shows the modulating signal is recovered, which is what is meant by *baseband*. There are also higher frequency products but these will be filtered away in a receiver. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideband
or see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation for a full math analysis that also considers phase.